# Minimum date per year with flag

Tags: sql, teradata

Hi I have following data in customer table.

```
CUST_ID     DATE
ab13563590  6/1/2008
ab13563591  1/1/2008
ab13563592  2/1/2008
ab13563593  8/1/2010
ab13563594  7/1/2010
ab13563595  9/1/2008
ab13563596  4/1/2008
ab13563597  10/1/2008
ab13563598  3/1/2009
ab13563599  5/1/2009
```

I need a calculated flag for which minimum date for every year will be 'Y' and 'N' for rest of them. Expected data should look like

```
CUST_ID       DATE    FLAG
ab13563590  6/1/2008    N
ab13563591  1/1/2008    Y
ab13563592  2/1/2008    N
ab13563593  8/1/2010    N
ab13563594  7/1/2010    Y
ab13563595  9/1/2008    N
ab13563596  4/1/2008    N
ab13563597  10/1/2008   N
ab13563598  3/1/2009    Y
ab13563599  5/1/2009    N
```

What I did is, I took group by year with min(date) and loaded data into temp table and join back to actual table and wrote a case statement. But I guess it can be solved  in a single select statement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using Window Functions:

```
SELECT cust_id,
    date,
    CASE WHEN date = min(date) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) ORDER BY date) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Flag
FROM table;
```

That will compare the date of the current row to the minimum date for the year. If they are equal, then you get a 'Y'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select cust_id,date,
case 
when date = (select min(date) as min_date from customer where to_char(cust.date,'yyyy') = to_char(date,'yyyy')) 
then 'Y' else 'N' end as flag
from customer cust
```